# Facebook share button disappear after UpdatePanel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook share button to share different pages from my page as described in [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/)  XFBML/HTML5 it doesn't matter.

First load will show all Facebook shares as expected
The problem happens when i update my page using UpdatePanel (asp.net) the Facebook share button **disappear**

I have tried putting the JavaScript inside pageLoad() or using Document.ready() without success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to parse the plugins again: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse

Just call `FB.XFBML.parse()` after the update.

Comment: Can you please give an example? I tried to run it and got error "Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined"

Comment: well, that means that the javascript sdk is not initialized. do you have a test link?

Comment: I was missing the Facebook sdk, strange enough everything works without this script... go figure, Thank you luschn

Comment: yeah, you only need the parse command if you create social plugins dynamically.